# Fazendo botões que alterem a aba num menu de tipo Bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap, aba

No momento, tenho o código a seguir:
https://pastecode.xyz/view/3f023c9b

O código em JavaScript a seguir tem o intuito de fazer com que os botões com os escritos "Anterior" e "Continuar", respectivamente, retornem e avancem uma aba. Porém, ao clicar, nada acontece.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prox(){
        $('.nav-tabs').find('.active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    }
    $('#btnA').click(function(){
        $('.nav-tabs').find('.active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    })
</script>
```

Os botões:

```
<div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="prox()">Salvar e Continuar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="btnA">Anterior</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem um erro aqui: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary onclick="prox()">`.... vc colocou o onclick dentro da class... seria: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="prox()">`... ou melhor, não fechou a class.

Comment: Erro meu redigindo o exemplo aqui. No código está certo.

Comment: Ok! Vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o evento:

```
$('#btnP').onclick(function(){
 $('.nav-tabs').find('.active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
})
```

para...

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // evita o submit
   $('.nav-tabs li a.active') // busca o <a> ativo
   .closest("li") // busca o <li> pai do <a> ativo
   .next(".nav-item") // seleciona o próximo <li>
   .find("a") // busca o <a> do próximo <li>
   .trigger('click'); // dispara o clique
});
```

Onde `#btn` é a `id` do botão <kbd>Carregar e continuar</kbd> e você precisa selecionar o pai do link `<a>` para selecionar o próximo link `<a>` dentro da próxima `<li>`.

O `e.preventDefault();` impede que a página seja recarregada pelo `submit`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu troquei o next pra prev pra poder utilizar no botão de voltar aba também. Inicialmente, só estava funcionando nas primeiras ocorrências de cada botão, então percebi que a razão era o fato de eu estar usando ids, que a princípio registram ocorrências singulares. Quando troquei de id para classe, tudo passou a funcionar.